# How to keep automatic dark mode in Google Chrome with Developer Tools closed

Tags: google-chrome, display, accessibility, dark-mode

I found that you can [enable automatic dark mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/rendering/apply-effects/#enable-automatic-dark-mode)  in Google Chrome, at least as long as you have the Developer Tools open.

However, as soon as I close the Developer Tools, the dark mode is gone.

Is there any way to keep the automatic dark mode on a tab even after closing the Developer Tools?

I am also open to suggestions for Google Chrome extensions for dark mode.

Comment: I would also like this. In the meantime I've been using "Dark Reader" for some time, it works really well but can be slow on complex sites (notably, Google's own Cloud Console). Chrome's native dark mode should be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Chrome exposes a Flag that allows you to force dark mode on "all web content" even when DevTools is closed. Navigate to `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` in your address bar and enable the feature.